# data saving in new collection is not working using mongoose-multi and gridfs stream?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs-stream

It is not possible to share all code here, but I am going you a hint.
I am adding my new collection's schema in the Schema file, which have two object global and local.
global and local are our two databases.

My question is Is there is anything another task I need to do, to use multi MongoDB's.
This project is also using gridfs steram with [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is just a small typo. So, the model is generated by mongoose-multi and it uses mongoose schema as name of the model with an extra 's'. So user becomes users. I know it is silly problem, but it is easy to forgot.